# (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf)) _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-parent"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a revision guide on Tkinter, The basics are working fine , however when i tried to put a frame within a frame ( Pressing Physics will show two more buttons , which each show a frame themselves) My Python code , is showing an error, so i created a new file where Physics itself is the start page , yet i'm getting this error when running it , i don't understand what's wrong, i've checked other answers and questions , yet i still don't understand what i'm doing wrong

> (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
>   _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-parent"

Here is my code

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Physics Equations", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PhysicsEquations"),bg="blue",fg="white",font=(None, 23, "bold"), height=2, width=11).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Physics Definitions", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PhysicsDefinitions"),bg="green",fg="white",font=(None, 23, "bold"), height=2, width=11).grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"),fg="white",bg="blue",width=10,font=(None,20,"bold"))
    button.grid()

class PhysicsEquations(tk.Frame):
def clickPhysicsEquations(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="This is Physics", font=controller.title_font,fg="white", bg="blue")
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    label1 = tk.Label(self, text=' ',bg="blue")
    label1.pack()
    try:
        file=open("physics_EQUATIONS.txt","r")
        data=file.read()
        file.close()
    except IOError:
        file=open("physics_EQUATIONS.txt","w+")
        file.write("Distance =  Speed x Time,")
        data=file.read()
        file.close()
    physics_equations=data.split(',') 
    temp=random.choice(physics_equations)
    used=[]
    used.append(temp)
    physics_equations.remove(temp)
    label1.configure(text=temp)

class PhysicsDefinitions(tk.Frame):
def clickPhysicsDefinitions(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    S = tk.Scrollbar(self)
    T = tk.Text(self, height=2 , width =100,bg="blue")
    S.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    T.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    S.config(command=T.yview)
    T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
    definitions="""Acceleration: Rate of change of velocity (affected by mass and force)."""
    T.insert(tk.END, definitions)
    button2=tk.Button(self, text="Definitions",command=clickPhysicsDefinitions,fg="white",bg="blue",width=10,font=(None,20,"bold"))
    button2.pack()
    button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"),fg="white",bg="blue",width=10,font=(None,20,"bold"))
    button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Sorry , if I made any mistakes on asking this question , first time asking.

Comment: When you create your three frames, you provide two named parameters: `parent` and `controller`.  `StartPage` is defined to take those two parameters, so it works.  The other two do not define an `__init__()` method of their own, so they inherit `Frame`'s constructor - which does not know about any such parameters.  It appears that the one method you defined in `PhysicsEquations` and `PhysicsDefinitions` was supposed to be an `__init__`, but you gave them some meaningless name instead.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code down to a [mcve]. For example, do we really need close to 50 lines of text to reproduce the problem, and do we really need three pages instead of one or two?

Comment: Sorry , for the length of the question,

Comment: Thank you Jason , that worked perfectly , i see where you coming from , the reason they were called "click...." was because this variation of code is my 5th attempt , at something like this , so i copied the functions without changing the names, again, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these two class definitions:

StartPage:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

PhysicsDefinitions:

```
class PhysicsDefinitions(tk.Frame):
    def clickPhysicsDefinitions(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

Notice the difference? One has an `__init__`, one doesn't. The one that doesn't depends on the implementation of `__init__` in the base class. You are calling this like `PhysicsDefinitions(parent=self, controller=self)` which gets turned into `Frame(parent=..., controller=...)` and `Frame` doesn't accept a named argument of `parent` or `controller`.

If you are going to pass arguments that aren't valid for the base class, you must create a custom `__init__` that accepts these parameters like in the first example.

Comment: Thank you for answering this , it works perfectly , again sorry for the length of the post , i'm still getting used to this.